# Google Sheets, extracting some part in the cell and concatenate information

Tags: regex, google-sheets, concatenation, formula, textjoin

I want to take some information from A1 and generate the link with it.

A1: FA-TI7176632 | NF-TTS9482154 | Stage: 6 | FA-OR7163850 | MT-TOR9475520

```
> ="https://worldinternal.com:8235/clinetpage.html?testid="+(A1, "FA-TI\d+))")
#generate the link in B1 with the part of A1
```

I only need "FA-TI7176632" information in A1 and want to add it to the link at the end. Please help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
="https://worldinternal.com:8235/clinetpage.html?testid="&
 REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "FA-TI\d+")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
=HYPERLINK("https://worldinternal.com:8235/clinetpage.html?testid=" &REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"FA-TI\d+"),REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"FA-TI\d+"))
```

[image]